# Compilar string como código

Tags: c#, .net, string, compilação, scripting

Há  como eu compilar uma string dentro do C#?
Exemplo: `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`.

Como se fosse um `eval()` do JavaScript?

Pois estava com um projeto de carregar um código dentro de um arquivo de texto ou outra coisa.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bom, já é possível gerar código arbitrário e executá-lo em tempo de execução. Mas não de um jeito simples, não desta forma fluida. Você já tinha [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101) ou introspecção como alguns preferem chamar no caso específico. Veja no final.

## [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101)

Já ouviu falar no [.NET Compiler Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) (antigo Roslyn)?

Ele é o compilador do C# 6.0 (vindo junto ao Visual Studio 2015 e posteriores).

O novo compilador é todo escrito em C# e traz algumas vantagens:

- está muito mais fácil de dar manutenção que a versão anterior escrita em C++;
- é *open source* (licença Apache, bem permissiva, faça praticamente o que quiser com ele);
- permite a participação da comunidade no seu desenvolvimento;
- permitirá melhorias na linguagem de forma mais rápida e barata;
- nos casos majoritários é mais rápido em computadores modernos;
- possui uma arquitetura chamada *Compiler As A Service*;

Este último é o que te interessa. Há uma API muito completa que facilita criar ferramentas adicionais para a linguagem de forma muito simples e garantidamente tratando tudo com o jeito correto e mais atual da linguagem porque é o compilador que está provendo todas as análises de código. As próprias ferramentas do Visual Studio passam a se basear totalmente no .NET Compiler Platform. Uma das ferramentas é converter código de C# p/ VB.NET e vice-versa de forma prática, precisa e simples.

Outra ferramenta que está sendo desenvolvida com ele é um [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) que é uma forma muito prática de testar códigos, aprender recursos da linguagem. Encurta muito o tempo de protótipos. O REPL é uma espécie de interpretador.

Basicamente a mesma API que permite criar o REPL resolve o seu problema.

## Engine Script

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp;

namespace RoslynScriptingDemo {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var engine = new ScriptEngine();
            engine.Execute(@"System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello Roslyn"");");
        }
    }
}
```

Esta API permite que você crie um *engine* de *script* que execute códigos arbitrários.

Outro exemplo um pouco mais complexo:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp;

namespace Test.ConsoleApp {
    public class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var engine = new ScriptEngine();

            var session = engine.CreateSession();

            session.AddReference("System");
            session.AddReference("System.Linq");

            session.Execute(@"using System;
                              var arr = new[] {1, 2, 6};
                              foreach (var i in arr) {
                                  if(i > 1) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
                              }"
                           );

            session.Execute(@"using System;
                              using System.Linq;
                              var arr = new[] {1, 2, 6};
                              var arrResult = arr.Where(x => x > 1);
                              foreach (var i in arrResult) {
                                  Console.WriteLine(i);
                              }"
                           );

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Eu imagino que não deve ser difícil para você carregar o texto do arquivo em uma *string* para executar. Mas no último CTP que eu vi, tinha um método para executar direto de um arquivo ao invés de uma *string*. Mas não faz muita diferença, é mais uma comodidade. A API é muito completa e muito fácil. Era algo assim:

```
scriptEngine.ExecuteFile("script.cs");
```

## Segurança

Evidentemente que códigos arbitrários que podem ser executados são perigosos. De onde vem esses *scripts*? Quem pode disponibilizá-los? Quem pode manipulá-los?

Claro que este sistema de *scripts* tem menos riscos que o [`eval`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101) do JavaScript. Mais difícil alguém conseguir injetar código malicioso em um sistema desenvolvido por você do que em uma página *web*. Mas se não tomar cuidados adequados, acontece do mesmo jeito.

De qualquer forma, quando você utiliza esse tipo de recurso tem que entender que existem riscos e eles precisam ser minimizados. Verificações extensivas antes de executar um arquivo vindo de fora precisam ser realizadas. Mas o mais importante é ter a consciência que há uma porta aberta para execuções maliciosas.

O C# já roda em uma espécie de *sandbox* e dá certas garantias para evitar certos problemas de segurança. Mas códigos arbitrários sempre podem fazer mais do que você espera.

Existe um outro aspecto que não é bem de segurança, que é o tratamento de exceções gerados no *script*. Isso precisa ser bem entendido. Mas é assunto que vai além da sua pergunta.

## Alternativa

Você pode hoje usar uma forma limitada e mais complicada disto através do [CodeDOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não vou entrar em detalhes já que não conheço o assunto muito bem, mas basicamente ele é composto por uma série de classes que permitem montar o código de execução originário de um código fonte. Mas já alerto que os próprios desenvolvedores do .NET entendem que é muito complexo e que o .NET Compiler Platform é que vai trivializar o uso de códigos arbitrários.

Ainda existe uma forma para emitir o [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101) (*assembly*) diretamente mas não é o que você precisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/Scripting.cs)

Comment: Nossa, CodeDOM era muito ruim... péssimas lembranças disso. O Roslyn já pode ser usado como está... li recentemente que já conseguiram buildar o Visual Studio inteiro com este projeto.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Sim, já dá para usar legal **experimentalmente** com o que tem no CodePlex. Pena que eles tiraram o REPL que existia nos CTPs anteriores. Mas vão colocar de novo. Apenas está sendo totalmente reestruturado. Bons desenvolvedores fazem isso :)  Além da ferramenta ser interessante lá vai ter as "boas práticas " que o pessoal adora de como fazer um interpretador (usar o *engine de script*) corretamente. Ainda bem que tem mais um para deixar claro que CodeDOM só se estiver em desespero mesmo e não puder esperar pelo Roslyn estar em produção.

Answer (score 10):

Uma possível solução é usar [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx).

Um exemplo de como usar:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] {"mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll"}, "teste.exe", true)
            {
                GenerateExecutable = true
            };
        CompilerResults compiledAssembly = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"
        using System;
        class Program {
          public static void Main() {
                Console.WriteLine(""Hello world."");
          }
        }");

        var errors = compiledAssembly.Errors
                                     .Cast<CompilerError>()
                                     .ToList();

        if (errors.Any())
        {
            errors.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            return;
        }

        Module module = compiledAssembly.CompiledAssembly.GetModules()[0];

        Type mt = null;
        if (module != null)
            mt = module.GetType("Program");

        MethodInfo methInfo = null;
        if (mt != null)
            methInfo = mt.GetMethod("Main");

        if (methInfo != null)
            Console.WriteLine(methInfo.Invoke(null, null));
    }
```

O código é compilado pela classe `CSharpCodeProvider` e pode ser posteriormente utilizado através de reflexão sobre a *assembly* gerada.

Pode encontrar outro exemplo [aqui](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/).