# Criar uma classe dinamicamente em C#

Tags: c#

Eu tenho uma classe "ClasseA" e essa possui um atributo "Atributo" protected.

```
public class ClasseA
{
    protected string Atributo { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public ClasseA (int codigo)
    {
        Codigo = codigo;
    }
    public string Concatena()
    {
        return this.Atributo + " - " + this.Codigo;
    }

}
```

Eu gostaria de criar classes em runtime que herdem dessa classe "A" e que as mesmas populassem o atributo 'Atributo'.

Comment: Por que a classe precisa ser criada dinamicamente? Existe algum motivo para isto? Até tem como fazer isto embora não seja uma classe de verdade que será criada ([ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Mas até onde eu sei não dá para usar em herança. Nem faria sentido. Acho que seu problema é outro. tente fornecer mais informações para indicar melhor o problema.

Comment: da uma olhada neste link, talvez seja o que você quer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms404245(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Até existe como criar classes de verdade com [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou o novo [.Net Compiler Platform](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) mas duvido que seja isto que você precisa, estes são recursos bem complexos para serem usados em situações nada triviais como parece ser esse problema. Eu acho que você só está querendo criar objetos parametrizados e não classes.

Comment: Pois eu utilizo essa classe base para incluir mapeamentos das entidades em um contexto que está abrigado em um container, e, o local que chama o método que "roda" essa inserção das entidades no contexto, verifica se a classe do contexto que irá receber as entidades, já não existe num dicionário interno e não permite que o mesmo ocorra mais de uma vez pelo mesmo tipo de classe. Logo, surgiu a ideia de criar em runtime instâncias de classes que herdem os métodos dessa classe base, para que não seja necessário 'codar' para cada contexto uma classe nova e utilizar essa classe genérica.

Comment: Existem dois métodos de gerar código em runtime, [`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e [`CodeDOM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `TypeBuilder` é extremamente difícil de usar pois trabalha ao nível de IL. Concordo com o @bigown, duvido seriamente que isto seja necessário para resolver o problema.

Comment: Pessoal anda rápido no gatilho :D Sim, dá pra criar classes de verdade em tempo de execução. Sim, dá pra criar herança em runtime. Sim, isso pode ser muito útil (muitos ORMs trabalham assim, herdando nossas entidades e acrescentando recursos a elas). Eu só acho que o AP já deve ter tentado algo e neste caso poderia mostrar o que já conseguiu e as dificuldades. A pergunta já serviu no mínimo para mostrar que existe algo que alguns nem sonhavam.

Comment: Criar instâncias de classes é muito diferente de criar classes. Instâncias não herdam nada, instâncias não precisam. Eu entendi o contexto geral mas ainda tenho dúvidas se a abordagem seria correta. Me parece que você está preso aos conceitos de OOP como se eles resolvessem qualquer coisa de forma simples. Existem outras formas de generalizar a solução se isto é tão importante. Se não for, não tem porque se dar ao trabalho. Veja alguma coisa sobre isto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15432/101

Comment: Pessoal, como podem fechar a pergunta por motivo de não ser claro? A pergunta está claríssima! @bigown Não tem nada a ver com escrever e compilar código C#. O .Net tem API específica para definição de tipos em runtime.

Comment: Se você acha a pergunta clara e sabe como resolver poste sua resposta usando a API. Eu acho que esse problema não precisa de nada disto mas se precisasse eu iriam usar o jeito mais prático e agora recomendado pela MS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O código abaixo define em runtime a `ClasseB` que herda da sua `ClasseA`, na qual eu adicionei campos privados para usar nas propriedades em vez de deixar isso por conta do compilador.

A abordagem que usei para que `ClasseB` sete a propriedade `Atributo` da `ClasseA` foi adicionando nela (na ClasseB) um novo construtor, com um parâmetro à mais.

Testado e funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y6M72F

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CriaClasseHerdandoOutra();
    }
    public static void CriaClasseHerdandoOutra() {

        AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");
        AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

        // define tipo "ClasseB" herdando de "ClasseA"
        Type typeClasseA = Type.GetType("ClasseA");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("ClasseB", TypeAttributes.Public, typeClasseA);
        
        // obtém informação de atributos da "ClasseA" que serão setados 
        // no novo construtor da classe filha "ClasseB"
        FieldInfo codigo = typeClasseA.GetField("_codigo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        FieldInfo atributo = typeClasseA.GetField("_atributo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        
        // cria no tipo "ClasseB" o construtor exigido por sua classe base
        Type[] parameterTypes = {typeof(int)};
        ConstructorBuilder ctor1 = tb.DefineConstructor(
            MethodAttributes.Public, 
            CallingConventions.Standard, 
            parameterTypes);

        // adiciona no construtor instruções para setar 
        // o atributo "Codigo" da classe base "ClasseA"
        ILGenerator ctor1IL = ctor1.GetILGenerator();
        ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, codigo);
        ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // cria no tipo "ClasseB" um novo construtor,
        // que recebe dois parâmetros
        Type[] parameterTypes2 = { typeof(int), typeof(string)};
        ConstructorBuilder ctor2 = tb.DefineConstructor(
            MethodAttributes.Public, 
            CallingConventions.Standard, 
            parameterTypes2);

        // adiciona no novo construtor instruções para setar 
        // os atributos "Codigo" e "Atributo" da classe base "ClasseA"
        ILGenerator ctor2IL = ctor2.GetILGenerator();
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, codigo);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, atributo);
        ctor2IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        
        // cria o tipo que foi definido para "ClasseB"
        Type ClasseBType = tb.CreateType();
        
        // cria uma instância da "ClasseB", que acaba de ser definida
        // em runtime (herdando de "ClasseA"), invocando seu novo construtor
        // de dois parâmetros.
        ClasseA objClasseB = (ClasseA)System.Activator.CreateInstance(ClasseBType, 1, "Rá!");
        
        // invoca o método "Concatena" da classe base "ClasseA",
        // o qual teve seu resultado afetado pela classe filha "ClasseB"
        Console.WriteLine(objClasseB.Concatena());
    }        
}

public class ClasseA
{
    protected string _atributo;
    protected int _codigo;
    
    protected string Atributo 
    { 
        get {return _atributo;}
        set {_atributo = value; }
    }
    public int Codigo 
    { 
        get {return _codigo;}
        set {_codigo = value; }
    }
    public ClasseA (int codigo)
    {
        Codigo = codigo;
    }
    public string Concatena()
    {
        return this.Atributo + " - " + this.Codigo;
    }
}
```

Referência: [documentação do AssemblyBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

A chave neste exemplo são as classes `TypeBuilder`, para definição de um tipo em runtime, e a `ILGenerator`, para adicionar instruções ao corpo dos métodos definidos.

Existem outras formas de conseguir resultado semelhante. A saber - [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e [Roslyn](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/RoslynTeam), liberado em abril deste ano ([um exemplo](http://vmelorocha.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/o-que-e-o-projeto-roslyn/)).

### Considerações sobre meu código

É claro que este código tem fins apenas didáticos e precisa ser bem mais legível se for utilizado. Também é possível generalizar este código e abstraí-lo para uma API mais bacana que atenda uma necessidade específica.

Além disso, imagino que você usaria [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) do .Net de para identificar quais propriedades alterar em vez de fazer isso com base no nome.

Um exemplo típico do uso deste tipo de engenharia (criar herança de classes em tempo de execução ou de compilação do projeto) é em frameworks que não querem obrigar o usuário a herdar suas classes mas precisam adicionar recursos aos objetos do usuário (*ORM*s, por exemplo).

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro implemente uma classe especial para construir outras classes. O seguinte código faz isso:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace TypeBuilderNamespace
{
    public class ObjectBuilder
    {
        public object MyObject { get; set; }
        // Key seria o nome da propriedade, e Value o tipo dela.
        public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; }

        public void CreateNewObject()
        {
            var myType = CompileResultType();
            MyObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        }

        public Type CompileResultType()
        {
            TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
            ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

            foreach (var field in Fields)
                CreateProperty(tb, field.Key, field.Value);

            Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
            return objectType;
        }

        private TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
        {
            var typeSignature = "DerivadaDeClasseA";
            var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature
                                , TypeAttributes.Public |
                                TypeAttributes.Class |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                                , null);
            return tb;
        }

        private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
                tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                  MethodAttributes.Public |
                  MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                  MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                  null, new[] { propertyType });

            ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

            setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var dicionario = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dicionario.Add("Atributo", typeof(String));

var objectBuilder = new ObjectBuilder {
    Fields = dicionario 
};

objectBuilder.CreateNewObject();
var objetoCriado = objectBuilder.MyObject;
```

PS: Eu nao testei esse código, e alguns ajustes podem ser necessários, mas é um ponto de partida.

Answer (score -1):

usar o `dynamic teste = new ExpandoObject();` fica bem mais facil ;)

Comment: Poderia explicar de forma breve pq essa opção/código é melhor e quais vantagens tem? Recomendo a leitura da [tour] para aprender o básico do site.