# Cálculos dinâmicos php

Tags: php

Existe possibilidade de fazer um cálculo em php, sendo que minhas operações matemáticas estão em uma variável?
Ex:

```
$operacao = '+';
$valor1 = 10;
$valor2 = 10;
$calculo = $valor1 .$operacao. $valor2;
```

Teria que dar Resultado 20, porém, por padrão do PHP ele concatena me trazendo uma string:

```
"10 + 10";
```

Comment: Só com `if else` ou `switch` exemplo: `if($operação === '+')`

Comment: Pois é, ia facilitar um monte se existisse, pois são vários cálculos e desta forma irá quadruplicar o numero de linhas.

Comment: O eval citado nao é muito recomendável

Comment: Existe algum outra forma de fazer isso @Ivcs?

Comment: Melhor um parser do que um eval

Comment: ⇨ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156657/como-retornar-um-resultado-v%C3%A1lido-a-partir-de-uma-opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, tem a função [eval()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) (`eval` *— Executa uma string como código PHP*).

```
$operacao = '+';
$valor1 = 10;
$valor2 = 10;
$calculo = "$valor1 $operacao $valor2";
eval('echo '.$calculo.';');
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/fork/B8djd8)

***Com função:***

```
function soma($n1,$n2)
{
    return $n1+$n2;
}

eval('echo soma(10,20);');
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/fork/Grczoi)

***Observação:*** Particularmente falando, eu não faria a soma assim, mas, uma vez eu tive que usar o [eval()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) para solucionar um problema particular sendo que o retorno vinha uma *função numa string* e *tinha que executar*, usei o [eval()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) e resolveu aquele determinado problema.

*Referencia:*

[***eval***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php)

[***Função eval() do PHP – Utilidades***](http://www.robsonak.com.br/funcao-eval-do-php-utilidades)

Comment: Se você quiser retornar para uma variável, segue o exemplo => $calculo = eval("return $valor1 $operacao $valor2;");

Comment: O eval executa toda a instrução, por isso até eu coloquei dentro do `eval` o `echo` e no final `;`, para ele somar e mostrar o resultado.

Comment: @LucaoA eu fiz uma edição para você ver como seria a chamada de um texto em si!

Comment: Entendi, @João. Fiquei curioso e também fui pesquisar. Achei interessante. Seria inviável utilizar dessa forma(para somar) ou estou errado ?

Comment: @LucaoA é como eu disse na observação: vai depender mesmo do cenário, mas, particularmente eu faria de outra forma, no exemplo que eu dei e foi real, um webservice retornava um função dentro de uma string para executar aquela função eu tinha que dar um eval para funcionar, não tinha outra forma, se você tiver formas mais simples acredito ser bem melhor, mas, fica como aprendizado, a pergunta foi muito boa.

Comment: Ótima explicação, acredito que só seria válido dar uma explanada dos cuidados ao se utilizar o `eval()`, pois o mesmo vai "ler" a variável e tentar executar um comando a partir dela, se não for bem utilizado pode abrir brechas gigantes de segurança;

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro serve isto [Eval é mocinho ou bandido](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/3635) ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é uma boa explicação, só acho que vale o alerta na resposta e não nos comentários além de que o link pode quebrar,  pois o `eval` não é um mocinho ou bandido, só precisa de certos cuidados para não ter problemas futuros (como muitas outras funções e recursos) :)

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro Pode linkar nos comentários e dar um up nele, assim ele fica em destaque, note que o autor da resposta nem tem mais conta no site, só existe a resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Verdade, não tinha visto este detalhe

Answer (score 2):

Não discordo do uso do `eval`, o problema é que se não dizer o tratamento dos dados podem ocorrer problemas na entrada de valores o que deixará de ser uma operação matemática para a ser uma injeção de código.

Ainda sim um simples "parser" pode resolver, um exemplo com `preg_match_all` seria assim:

```
preg_match_all('#(\d\.\d+|\d+|[\+\-\/\*])#', $input, $output);
var_dump($output[0]);
```

Ele extrai todos valores inteiros, com ponto flutuante e operadores simples, claro que ainda é possível injetar caracteres inválidos, no caso faça uma checagem do input, assim:

```
if (preg_match('#^(\d|\d\.\d)([\d\+\-\s\/\*]+|\d+\.\d+)(\d|\d\.\d)+$#', $input) > 0) {

    preg_match_all('#(\d\.\d+|\d+|[\+\-\/\*])#', $input, $output);
    var_dump($output[0]);
}
```

Ainda teremos o problema da pessoa fazer cálculos assim:

```
2 2 3 + - /
```

Mas você pode resolver checando no loop o ultimo valor, um exemplo completo que fiz:

```
<?php

class SimpleMath
{
    private static function subcalc($a, $b, $operator)
    {
        switch ($operator)
        {
            case '-':
                return $a - $b;
            break;
            case '+':
                return $a + $b;
            break;
            case '*':
                return $a * $b;
            break;
            case '/':
                return $a / $b;
            break;
        }
    }

    public static function parse($input)
    {
        $input = trim($input);

        if (preg_match('#^(\d|\d\.\d)([\d\+\-\s\/\*]+|\d+\.\d+)(\d|\d\.\d)+$#', $input) > 0) {
            preg_match_all('#(\d\.\d+|\d+|[\+\-\/\*])#', $input, $output);
            $pre = $output[0];
            $j = count($pre);
            $operator = null;
            $final = null;

            for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
                var_dump($pre[$i]);

                switch ($pre[$i]) {
                    case '-':
                    case '+':
                    case '*':
                    case '/':
                        if ($op !== null) {
                            //Se já houver um operador "preparado" e tentar adicionar outro força um erro
                            throw new Exception('Erro na ordem dos operadores');
                        }

                        $op = $pre[$i];
                    break;
                    default:
                        if ($final === null){
                            $final = $pre[$i];
                        } else if ($operator === null) {
                            //Se o anterior não era um operador força um erro
                            throw new Exception('Erro, falta um operador');
                        } else if (is_numeric($pre[$i])) {
                            $final = self::subcalc($final, $pre[$i], $operator);
                            //Remove operador usado
                            $operator = null;
                        } else {
                            //Se o numero na sequencia for invalido força um erro
                            throw new Exception('Formato do numero é invalido');
                        }
                }
            }

            return $final;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Input invalido');
        }
    }
}

var_dump( SimpleMath::parse('2 * 2 - 1') );
```

> Não funciona para cálculos avançados, mas basta você adaptar e adicionar condições e ou operadores, também tem o caso de usar os parenteses assim que possivel irei criar um exemplo que suporte algo como `(1 * 2) - (3 /4)`