# (php/laravel) Como faço para calcular expressões matemáticas?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Preciso fazer cálculos de forma com o php, por exemplo, terei um campo em que irei colocar a 2 + 9 (4 * 8) / 6 e me retornará o resultado, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer.Segue um exemplo de como estou precisando:

http://pt.numberempire.com/equationsolver.php/equationsolver.php#menu

Comment: É isso: fazer o calculo matemático a partir da string já composta: "3 + 2 = 5"

Answer (score 1):

Deixo aqui uma maneira sem usar `eval()`, para isso já tem uma resposta que foi feita há mais tempo cujo @Bacco colocou o link em cima da pergunta:

```
function callback1($m) {return c($m[1]);}
function callback2($n,$m) {
    $o=$m[0];
    $m[0]=' ';
    return $o=='+' ? $n+$m : ($o=='-' ? $n-$m : ($o=='*' ? $n*$m : $n/$m));
}
function c($s){ 
    while ($s != ($t = preg_replace_callback('/\(([^()]*)\)/','callback1',$s))) $s=$t;
        preg_match_all('![-+/*].*?[\d.]+!', "+$s", $m);
        return array_reduce($m[0], 'callback2');
}

$str = '(3 + 2) * 5';
echo c($str);
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/L9Ayib)

Fonte: Excelente resposta retirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928563/evaluating-a-string-of-simple-mathematical-expressions#929681)

Comment: Não acho adequado nem pra esse :)

Comment: Se eval() é a resposta, você está fazendo a pergunta errada. - Rasmus Lerdorf

Comment: @Miguel como indicado nos seus links, um pequeno parser. Dá mais trabalho do que um simples eval na hora de implementar, mas garante um sossego futuro que não tem preço :)

Comment: Não discordo e nem sou a favor do uso do eval, se tomar cuidado com os dados na entrada pode funcionar bem, mas o que recomendo é pesquisar se a pergunta não é duplicata, sempre marque quando for dup http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134015/3635

Comment: O cálculo não bate usando esse método.

Comment: Qual é o calculo? @Rafael

Comment: Tipo assim: $calculo = "(89*12)*14-17/2"; eval('echo '.$calculo.';'); O resultado tem que dar: 14943.5. Tive que fazer colocar uma expressão regular para poder usar dessa forma.

Comment: Vou ver, 2 mins

Comment: Percebi @Rafael, o problema é que esta função não respeita as leis da matemática, primeiro multiplicação/divisão e só depois soma/subtração. Desculpa ):