# Como executar código arbitrário no Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

Eu uso uma linguagem xBase que possui [macro substituição](https://harbour.github.io/ng/c53g01c/ng110bc2.html) como no Clipper original. Existe algo equivalente no Python? Usamos muito a montagem de linhas de comandos via menus em tempo de execução. Por exemplo, confecção de filtros.

Comment: seria algo tipo isso?
[http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/]
isso acessa bem as tabela do DBase, dai pra montar menus no python é moleza, quase igual ao clipper
tem esse tambem ó:
http://python-xbase-module.soft112.com/

Comment: Esta pergunta me fez voltar ao começo de minha carreira :).  Tanto o Python como o php tem o eval. Mas é bom ter cuidado pois o processamento pode ser diferente da forma como fazíamos no xbase. Já existe uma seção no SE para os fans de vi (outro veterano), quem sabe não seria uma oportunidade de fazermos uma para o xbase/clipper/foxpro?

Comment: A resposta postada resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução apresentada foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que ela é satisfatória. Também pode votar em toda e qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo. Aceitar e votar são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 3):

Tenho grande experiência com Clipper, trabalhei na maior usuária do mundo dessa linguagem que tinha acesso privilegiado à fornecedora da linguagem e participava do grupo dos desenvolvedores do Harbour, o substituto do Clipper.

Posso dizer para você que se usava macro, usava a linguagem de forma errada. Dá para fazer tudo sem ela e sempre é melhor fazer assim (a não ser que queria que compilasse algo em *runtime*, o que só o Harbour tem algo melhor, o Clipper não tinha).

Em todas as linguagens esse tipo de coisa é problemática e não recomendada. Até onde seria interessante usar (só consigo pensar em um caso), o jeito correto é fazer algo mais apropriado (mesmo que seja mais complexo). Existe soluções melhores, mesmo para os casos citados na pergunta. Macro foi uma criação do dBase II porque não existia uma linguagem de programação (sequer tinha *array*) e esse era o jeito de resolver algumas coisas. O dBase III já deu melhores soluções para grande parte das questões sem uso de macro. O Clipper, principalmente o 5, resolveu quase todos os outros casos, e o Harbour matou de vez a necessidade de macro.

Se quiser cometer o mesmo erro em Python, a função [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) é o que procura. Mas ressalto que ela é inerentemente insegura e desnecessária. Claro que se souber bem o que está fazendo, até pode usar e pode adicionar a segurança necessárias antes do uso, mas é complicado usar certo, em geral vale mais a pena fazer de outra forma.

Relacionado: [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101)