# Concatenar itens em um vetor

Tags: array, python-2.7, concatenação-de-string

Possuo o seguinte vetor, que obtenho após consultar um banco de dados:

```
a = ['[[10, 20], 10]']
```

Quando tento acessar os seus valores através dos índices, não consigo.

Por exemplo, se digitar: `print(a[0][0])`. É Retornado `'['`

Já tentei fazer: `b = ''.join(a)` efetuar o print. Porém, essa situação continua.

Preciso que esse vetor seja convertido "realmente" em um vetor.

Por exemplo, caso eu queira consultar o valor `[10, 20]`, eu faça `print(a[0])`. Se quiser consultar o 20, `print(a[0][1])`

Já tentei muitas soluções (com join, numpy e etc...). Alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: Mas o que você está recebendo do banco é uma *string*, não uma lista. O objeto `a` é uma lista com apenas um valor, do tipo *string*.

Comment: Sim. Você está correto! Existe alguma forma de arrumar essa situação.
Pergunto, porque realmente não sei @AndersonCarlosWoss.

Comment: Danilo, o que representa esses valores? Por quê eles estão armazenados assim na tabela?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está recebendo do banco de dados parece ser uma lista de apenas um valor *string*, então você não conseguirá acessar os valores como se fosse uma lista. O que você pode fazer, e funciona para este caso em específico, é converter sua *string* para uma lista através de uma análise JSON:

```
import json

a = ['[[10, 20], 10]']

lista = json.loads(a[0])

print(lista[0])    # [10, 20]
print(lista[0][1]) # 20
```

Mas se isso está vindo do banco de dados, há sérios indícios que suas tabelas estão mal estruturadas.

Comment: Muito Obrigado. @Anderson Carlos Woss!
Vou revisar a tabela. Porém, a tabela é para uso pessoal, bem simples mesmo.
Mas, agradeço o comentário. Caso fosse uma aplicação comercial, seria modificada com certeza!

Answer (score 3):

O retorno que você recebe do banco de dados é uma string que representa a sintaxe de uma lista Python, não um lista em si. Para usá-la como lista, você precisa que o Python interprete o trecho de código que ela representa, e para fazer isso existem algumas opções.

---

### ast.literal_eval()

Considerando que a string contém código Python e se trata de uma estrutura literal (`string`, `number`, `tuple`, **`list`**, `dict`, `boolean` ou `None`), você pode utilizar a função [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). A biblioteca `ast` possibilita a interpretação programática da sintaxe Python, de forma que a função em questão recebe uma string de estrutura literal e a retorna interpretada em tempo de execução:

```
>>> import ast
>>> retorno = '[[10, 20], 10]'
>>> a = ast.literal_eval(retorno)
>>> print(a[0][0])
10
>>> print(a[0][1])
20
```

(exemlo no repl.it: https://repl.it/M4fP/1)

---

### json.loads()

Como o seu exemplo de string para parse também representa um array JSON, pode-se utilizar o [parser de JSON do Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) para interpretá-la com segurança, como mostrado pelo @anderson-carlos-woss na resposta aceita:

```
>>> import json
>>> retorno = '[[10, 20], 10]'
>>> a = json.loads(retorno)
>>> print(a[0][0])
10
>>> print(a[0][1])
20
```

(exemplo no repl.it: https://repl.it/M4fP/2)

---

### yaml.safe_load

Parsers de outras linguages de serialização que utilizem representação de arrays igual à do JSON, como o [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) ([na verdade JSON é um "subgrupo" do YAML](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/11/22/json-yaml-but-yaml-json)), também podem lhe ser úteis. O YAML, particularmente, possui uma função `safe_load()`:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> retorno = '[[10, 20], 10]'
>>> a = yaml.safe_load(retorno)
>>> print(a[0][0])
10
>>> print(a[0][1])
20
```

(exemplo no repl.it: https://repl.it/M4fP/3)

Mais sobre o YAML parser e entrada de dados segura em programas Python: [Openstack: Avoid dangerous file parsing and object serialization libraries](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_avoid-dangerous-input-parsing-libraries.html)

---

### eval() (alto risco de segurança)

A opção **menos segura** é o uso da função [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). Ela recebe uma string de código Python e a executa:

```
>>> retorno = '[[10, 20], 10]'
>>> a = eval(retorno)
>>> print(a[0][0])
10
>>> print(a[0][1])
20
```

(exemplo no repl.it: https://repl.it/M4fP/0)

A falta de segurança se deve ao fato de a função `eval()` executar **todo e quaquer código** passado. Portanto, os resultados podem ser catastróficos se algum usuário malicioso for capaz de alterar os dados do seu banco para que a variável `retorno` contenha algum comando indesejado. Via de regra, não utilize `eval()` mesmo que você confie na string, pois nunca se sabe como ela pode ser interceptada por alguém.

---

Para mais informações acerca do perigo no uso de `eval()`:

[Stack Overflow: Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128851/20363)

[Ned Batchelder: Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

[Kevin London: Dangerous Python Functions, Part 1](https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/07/26/dangerous-python-functions.html)

Comment: Por que o downvote? Falei alguma bobagem? O exemplo acima funciona no console Python.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @nunks.lol!

Comment: (o downvote não é meu), mas deve ser por que "eval" não é uma coisa pra se usar light-hearted, sendo uma instrução com seríssimos problemas de segurança - além de problemas de performance.
Se a string contém uma expressão em Python, o melhor é usar `import ast; ast.liteteral_eval` - que só converte valores literais: se alguém colocar strings com chamadas de função ou expressões em python no banco. elas não serão executadas. 
Outra opção, no caso, é usar o parser de JSON para a coluna - ainda mais tranquilo que o `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Por exemplo, se alguém colocar essa string aqui no seu banco de dados e tiver um eval: `__import__("os").system("rm -rf /")` - ja era.

Comment: (a minha preocupação não é você ter colocado o eval - tá todo mundo aqui pra aprender.  A minha preocupação são justamente os upvotes para a sua resposta - mas mude para o ast.literal_eval, e acrescente algum link para os perigos do eval puro, que essa resposta passa a ser uma contribuição bem legal para o S.O.)

Comment: @jsbueno Entendo os riscos do uso de eval, só pensei na solução mais simples, sem `import`, e não atinei que poderia ser algo tão nocivo em uma resposta devido a credibilidade inerente aos upvotes. Concordo plenamente com essa posição e vou elaborar melhor a resposta para que sirva como um alerta quanto ao uso de eval. Obrigado! =)