# Qual a diferença entre essas formas de execução de comando?

Tags: python, lista, int

Esses comandos em Python:

```
lista = eval('[' + input("Digite sua lista: ") + ']')
```

E esse:

```
lista = input("Digite sua lista: ")
```

E esse:

```
lista = [int(x) for x in input().strip()]
```

Por que esse último dá o erro abaixo?

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `lista = eval('[' + input("Digite sua lista: ") + ']')`

Não use [`eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101) se não dominar profundamente a linguagem e a computação. Em essência não precisa dele.

> `lista = input("Digite sua lista: ")`

Está pedindo para digitar algo e guardar na variável como uma *string*, não uma lista.

> `lista = [int(x) for x in input().strip()]`

Está criando uma lista (um *array* de tamanho dinâmico). Isto é chamado compreensão de expressão, então esse laço é executado e o resultado de toda execução do laço, ou seja, todos os passos, são guardados na lista.

Neste caso está pegando a *string* gerada na digitação do dado (`input()`) e separando as palavras (`strip()`) e em cada dado é transformado em um inteiro (`int()`), esperando que o texto digitado separado por espaços sejam números.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','

Foi digitado um texto que não pode ser convertido para um número. Eu não gosto dessa estratégia, mas em Python costuma-se capturar exceção quando isto ocorre para corrigir.