# Eval do Javascript. Qual o porquê dele ser inseguro?

Tags: javascript, escopo-de-variáveis, eval

Bom, estava lendo sobre o `eval` do Javascript e me deparei com um monte de perguntas no meu cérebro nas quais envolve sobre ele ser inseguro e escopo.

Por que ele é inseguro?

Por que e considerado um terceiro escopo?

Por que ele e considerado uma forma de cria códigos de maneira dinâmica? 
ao meu vê tudo em JS e executado de maneira dinâmica...

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128845/eval-%C3%A9-mocinho-ou-bandido

Comment: Ele vai pegar qualquer trecho de código e executar. Se tiver lá um `drop database` sendo enviado para o seu servidor (e ele aceitar o comando, é óbvio), então perdeu tudo. O `eval` é muito útil quando você mesmo altera um trecho de código seu mesmo, nem tanto quando você tenta interpretar um código alheio

Comment: Eu também costumo me fazer essa pergunta as vezes: Como pode ser o `eval` perigoso no Javascript, sendo que de todo jeito ele será interpretado no Browser do cliente?

Comment: Imagine que você tá numa página que tenha `eval(data);`. Se `data` for a resposta de um webservice e por acaso ele, em vez de devolver os dados, devolver `"location.href='http://welcome.to.hell.com/'"`; o que você acha que seria a consequência disso, na internet em geral e especialmente para quem entrar nesse teu site, com esse `eval()`?