# Como forçar a interpolação de strings quando uma vem do banco de dados?

Tags: php

Supondo que eu possua a variável:

```
$nome = "John Due";
```

Quando eu faço:

```
$mensagem = "Seja bem-vindo, {$nome}";
```

Terei o resultado "Seja bem-vindo, John Due", isso porque defini a minha string com interpolação diretamente no código. Entretanto, o que preciso fazer é armazenar essa string template no banco de dados e continuar obtendo o mesmo resultado. Se hoje eu armazeno a string acima em uma coluna do banco e a exibo, o resultado que tenho é "Seja bem-vindo, {$nome}", como se a interpolação não ocorresse.

Há uma forma de forçar a interpolação das strings quando o conteúdo vem do banco de dados?

Uma forma equivalente, lendo a string template da entrada do usuário ao invés de lê-la do banco de dados pode ser vista no [ideone](https://ideone.com/LzXQ87), mostrando que a interpolação da string não ocorre, mesmo utilizando {$nome} no seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A interpolação funciona quando a *string* é tratada diretamente pelo interpretador do PHP. Como ela é estática no código, ele consegue analisá-la e gerar a estrutura necessária para a interpolação das informações.

Quando uma *string* é armazenada no banco de dados, ela deixa de ser avaliada diretamente pelo interpretador por questões de segurança. Como o conteúdo vem de fontes externas, entende-se que o desenvolvedor não terá total controle sobre o conteúdo e, portanto, decidiu-se não avaliá-lo para evitar possíveis brechas de segurança.

Uma forma bem sensível de se resolver é indicar para o interpretador que ele deverá avaliar a *string* daquela maneira e isso é feito através da função [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php). Com o `eval` você assume que a fonte dos dados é segura e que avaliar a interpolação da *string* não irá expor nenhum dado sensível da aplicação.

Considerando

```
// Texto vindo do banco de dados:
$smsQuery->message = "Você Possui Fatura em Aberto. Fatura: {$destinatario->identificador}";
$destinatario->identificador = "687918";
```

Ao realizar `eval($smsQuery->message)` a *string* seria avaliada, ocorrendo a interpolação dos valores.

- [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/5878)

Outra forma é fazer a tradução de caracteres da sua *string*. Ao invés de definir, por exemplo:

```
"Você Possui Fatura em Aberto. Fatura: {$destinatario->identificador}"
```

Você pode fazer

```
"Você Possui Fatura em Aberto. Fatura: {{identificador}}"
```

E no PHP fazer a devida tradução dos caracteres:

```
$dados = ['{{identificador}}' => $destinatario->identificador];

echo strtr($smsQuery->message, $dados);
```

Assim, você, como desenvolvedor, terá total controle sobre os dados expostos através do *array* `$dados`. Valores que não estiverem previstos nesse *array* não serão alterado e permanecerão na *string* final.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8s6Wcz).

Comment: Outra opção: [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: @bfavaretto Não sei se `sprintf` caberá nesse caso, pois como o número de variáveis no template pode variar, não terá como saber quais valores substituir. O template ficaria `"Olá %s"` e não saberíamos por qual variável substituir.

Comment: É, com `sprintf` não dá pra ser tão automático, mas é uma opção meio que consolidada para se armazenar templates. Mas concordo que é ruim perder a semântica das variáveis.

Comment: Utilizando o strtr funcionou perfeitamente, mas agora vou ter que desenvolver algo para recuperar todos os nomes dos campos da query, para adicionar na matriz $dados, pois serão as variáveis disponíveis para utilizar dentro da $smsQuery->message

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de agradecer muito pela ajuda, acabei utilizando str_replace, achei que ficou melhor, segue como ficou meu método, estou utilizando Laravel.

```
public function EnviarSMSInadimplentes()
    {

        try
        {
            $smsQuerys = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM  SMS"));

            foreach($smsQuerys as $smsQuery):

                $destinatarios = DB::select(DB::raw($smsQuery->query));

                foreach($destinatarios as $destinatario):

                    $variaveis = array();
                    $valores   = array();

                    $camposQuery =  DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('V_SGI_SMSINADIMPLENTES');

                    foreach($camposQuery as $campo):
                        $campo = strtolower($campo);
                        $variaveis[] = "#$campo#";
                        $valores[] = $destinatario->$campo;
                    endforeach;

                    $message = str_replace($variaveis, $valores, $smsQuery->message);
                    //die($message);

                    EnviarSmsJob::dispatch($smsQuery->proccess,$destinatario->identificador,'550000000000',$message,$smsQuery->identifiertype)
                                    ->delay(now()->addMinutes(0))
                                    ->onQueue('SMS');
                endforeach;

            endforeach;
        }
         catch(Exception $e)
         {
            echo 'Ocorreu algum erro no processo';
         }

    }
```

Abaixo a string armazenada no campo message da tabela SMS, recuperado através da propriedade: $smsQuery->message

Fatura #identificador# #vencimento#