# Array no str_replace do PHP

Tags: php

Tenho armazenado em uma tabela, um modelo de declaração:

> Declaro para devido fins que o _________ matrícula _______ compareceu na empresa no dia
>   ______ às _______ para prestar o serviço de __________

Só que estou querendo trocar o ______ pelos dados que vem do banco. Eis minhas tentativas frustradas:

Query:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM....");
$pe = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
```

Tentativa 1:

```
$texto = $visualizar->Modelo;
$buscar = array("____","____","____","____","____");
$alterar = array($pe->Nome,$pe->Matricula,date("d/m/Y"),date("H:i"),$pe->Servico);
$incluir = str_replace($buscar,$alterar,$texto);
echo $incluir;
```

Tentativa 2:

```
$texto = $visualizarD[1]->Modelo;
$buscar = array("____","____","____","____","____");
$alterar = array($pe->Nome,$pe->Matricula,date("d/m/Y"),date("H:i"),$pe->Servico);
$incluir = '';
  foreach($alterar as $altera)
  {
    $incluir .= str_replace($buscar,$altera,$texto);
  }
echo $incluir;
```

Tentativa 3:

```
$texto = $visualizarD[1]->Modelo;
$buscar = array("____","____","____","____","____");
$alterar = array($pe->Nome,$pe->Matricula,date("d/m/Y"),date("H:i"),$pe->Servico);
$incluir = '';
  for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
  {
    $incluir .= str_replace($buscar[$i],$altera[$i],$texto);
  }
echo $incluir;
```

Enfim, em todas elas deram erradas. As 02 últimas repetia o texto sendo que em cada texto repetido, os campos ______ eram preenchidos pelos nomes que desejo alterar, mas cada nome em um determinado texto.

Só gostaria de ressaltar que essa minha dúvida não tem nada a ver com o meu post anterior, do qual consegui resolver com sucesso. Nesse caso, preciso fazer o inverso.

Comment: Bom, sempre serão 5 dados a serem substituídos?

Comment: Olá Filipe. Isso. Os 05 dados virão do banco de dados.

Comment: E essa não resolve o problema? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360697/5878

Comment: Então como sugestão, e também para facilitar a leitura, sugiro que você substitua o "_" por  ou #1, #2, #3... e depois apenas faça um replace da informação.

Comment: Perfeito Filipe. Tem razão, troquei o ___ por #1, #2, #3, #4, #5 e funcionou. Muito obrigado. Caso queira colocar como resposta, marcarei como aceita.

Comment: Olá Anderson, obrigado pelo link, mas a informação do Filipe me ajudou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então como sugestão, e também para facilitar a leitura, sugiro que você substitua o "_" por ou #1, #2, #3... e depois apenas faça um replace da informação

Segue os códigos com os dois exemplos.

```
<?php
$texto = "Declaro para devido fins que o #1 matrícula #2 compareceu na empresa no dia #3 às #4 para prestar o serviço de #5";


$textoNovo = str_replace("#1", 'Fulano', $texto);
$textoNovo = str_replace("#2", '012345', $textoNovo);
$textoNovo = str_replace("#3", '10/10', $textoNovo);
$textoNovo = str_replace("#4", '10h', $textoNovo);
$textoNovo = str_replace("#5", 'estudos', $textoNovo);

echo $textoNovo;


$texto = "Declaro para devido fins que o _____ matrícula _____ compareceu na empresa no dia _____ às _____ para prestar o serviço de _____";


$textoNovo = preg_replace("/_____/", 'Fulano', $texto, 1);
$textoNovo = preg_replace("/_____/", '012345', $textoNovo, 1);
$textoNovo = preg_replace("/_____/", '10/10', $textoNovo, 1);
$textoNovo = preg_replace("/_____/", '10h', $textoNovo, 1);
$textoNovo = preg_replace("/_____/", 'estudos', $textoNovo, 1);

echo $textoNovo;
```

Comment: Ao invés de várias chamadas à `str_replace`, você pode usar a `strtr` como indiquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360697/5878. Com ela você define um *array* e substitui tudo de uma vez.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo, obrigado. :)