# Criar função para fazer cálculos com um determinado operador utilizando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Não sei se daria certo, ou se seria a melhor opção, mas eu tenho um código que consiste no seguinte:

Situando que o valor `operacao` venha com o argumento `+`, e eu queira usar ele para somar dois valores. Como eu deveria fazer?

Exemplo:

```js
function calcular(operacao){

    var num1 = 6, num2 = 2;

    var resultado = num1 + operacao + num2;
    mostrarVisor(resultado);
}

function mostrarVisor(result){

    document.getElementById('visor').innerHTML = result;    
    // aqui eu escrevo o resultado na tela!                     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Para não usar o `eval`, [que pode trazer alguns riscos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128845/eval-%C3%A9-mocinho-ou-bandido), você pode criar uma função que faz uso do `switch` para determinar a operação.

Algo assim:

```js
function operate(x, y, op) {
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      return x + y;
    case '-':
      return x - y;
    case '*':
      return x * y;
    case '/':
      return x / y;
    default:
      throw new Error('Invalid operator.');
  }
}

console.log(operate(4, 3, '+')); // 7
console.log(operate(6, 4, '-')); // 2
console.log(operate(3, 3, '*')); // 9
console.log(operate(8, 2, '/')); // 4
```

Mas você ainda pode utilizar o `eval`, se desejar. Sugiro apenas que crie uma série de validações para se assegurar que nenhum código arbitrário será executado:

```js
const isNumber = (val) => typeof val === 'number';

function operate(x, y, op) {
  const validOperators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];

  if (!isNumber(x) || !isNumber(y) || !validOperators.includes(op)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid arguments.');
  }

  return eval(`${x} ${op} ${y}`);
}

console.log(operate(4, 3, '+')); // 7
console.log(operate(6, 4, '-')); // 2
console.log(operate(3, 3, '*')); // 9
console.log(operate(8, 2, '/')); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Amgio, acredito que o que você esteja procurando seja o método `eval()`, ele recebe uma String, e se ela for uma expressão o eval irá calcular o resultado:

```
eval("1 + 1");
```

A saída do comando a cima será `2`