# Como colocar a operação (soma, multiplicação) dentro de uma variável

Tags: javascript, lógica

Bom dia!

Estou estudando lógica de programação com JS e gostaria de saber como pedir ao usuário que ele digite a operação, então o JS interpreta isso e gera o resultado...

```
 <script>
     var n1 = prompt('Digite um número');
     n1 = parseInt(n1);
     var n2 = prompt('Digite outro número');
     n2 = parseInt(n2);
     var operacao = prompt('Digite a operação:')

     var resultado = (n1+operacao+n2);


     alert("O resultado da mutiplicação é: " + resultado)
 </script>
```

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Para esse exercício didático, o desaconselhado `var resultado = eval((n1+operacao+n2));` resolve, mas para um melhor aprendizado, você teria que criar uma função que verifica o operador e se n1 e n2 foram informados corretamente como números para obter o resultado esperado, com plus de verificação de n2 não poder ser igual a zero na operação de divisão.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Criar função para fazer cálculos com um determinado operador utilizando JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410573/criar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-fazer-c%c3%a1lculos-com-um-determinado-operador-utilizando-javascri)

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode usar o if para verificar a operação, exemplo:

```
    <script>
         var n1 = prompt('Digite um número');
         n1 = parseInt(n1);
         var n2 = prompt('Digite outro número');
         n2 = parseInt(n2);
         var operacao = prompt('Digite a operação:')

       //Podes ate testar se é um dos operadores que  o usuário digitou
        if(operacao !=="-" ||operacao !=="+" ||operacao !=="/" ||operacao !=="*"){
           alert("Informe um operador Válido");
           return false;   
         }

 //Pode fazer um if pra testar tbm se é numero ou letra que digitou e por ai vaiii

         var resultado = (n1+operacao+n2);

             if(operacao ==="+")
                resultado = n1 + n2;

             if(operacao ==="*")
                resultado = n1 * n2;


               if(operacao ==="/" && n2 > 0)
                resultado = n1 / n2;

              if(operacao ==="-")
                resultado = n1 - n2;




         alert("O resultado da Operação é: " + resultado)
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de solucionar o seu caso é usando um switch...case:

```
var resultado = 0
switch (operacao){
  case '+':
    resultado = n1 + n2
    break
  case '-':
    resultado = n1 - n2
    break
  case '*':
    resultado = n1 * n2
    break
  case '/':
    resultado = n1 / n2
    break
  default:
    alert('operação não permitida')
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Javascript não é possível, em nível sintático, passar um operador aritmético como argumento. O que dá para fazer é  juntar os números de entrada em um array e utilizar o método [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para executar uma função de redução específica que no caso seria uma função aritmética indicada por uma string definida pelo usuário.

```js
//  Cada índice desse objeto corresponde a uma operação aritmética 
//a ser passada por referência
let operaçãoAritimética = {
  '+': function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  },
  '-': function(x, y) {
    return x - y;
  },
  '*': function(x, y) {
    return x * y;
  },
  '/': function(x, y) {
    return x / y;
  }
};

let valores = [];
valores.push(parseInt(prompt('Digite um número')));
valores.push(parseInt(prompt('Digite outro número')));

let operação = prompt('Digite a operação(+, -, *, /):')

//  Cada string passada em operação corresponde a uma função redutora
//aplicada em valores.
let result = valores.reduce(operaçãoAritimética[operação]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o voto negativo?

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito simples de fazer o que quer é usando a função [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) do JavaScript, mas é uma função perigosa, deve ser usada com cautela na criação de sistemas. Como você está estudando só algoritmos, não vejo muito problema em usá-la. Essa função computa (interpreta) uma string como um código. A string, quando passada para ela, é executada, como se você a digitasse no console.

Vou fazer abaixo um exemplo do que quer usando essa função.

```js
function efetuaOperacao(){
   var n1 = prompt('Digite um número');
   n1 = parseInt(n1);
   var n2 = prompt('Digite outro número');
   n2 = parseInt(n2);
   var operacao = prompt('Digite a operação:')
   var resultado = eval(n1+operacao+n2);
   alert('O resultado da operação é ' + resultado + '.')
}

efetuaOperacao()
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma opção é você utilizar o operador [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Porém, pode acarretar em problemas, uma vez que, o contexto do **JS** será exposto nos comandos do [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp).

Uma solução ideal, porém complexa, seria você criar algo parecido com um [compilador](https://medium.com/@henriquesosa/seja-um-compilador-crie-um-compilador-com-javascript-33a9557c8cdf).

Comment: De fato, a solução que propus transcende a ideia de aprendizagem de lógica de programação, não recomendo que você utilize, a solução ideal seria às apresentadas abaixo, como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433343/173702)