# Uso do eval. Há alguma alternativa nesse caso?

Tags: javascript, eval

Me deparei com as funcionalidades do `eval()` e comecei a utilizar, porém fiquei sabendo do risco em utilizar `eval()` junto a um *input* externo.

Utilizo o `eval()` para receber de um *input-text* a *string* que corresponde a uma função polinomial. Foi a alternativa mais prática a curto prazo que consegui passar um dado do usuário como variáveis e operações matemáticas.

Há riscos em hospedar futuramente um código com essa função? Há alguma alternativa para o `eval()` nessa função?

```
function inserirLinhaTabela() 
{

    //Cálculo numérico: 

    var poli = document.getElementById("fx").value;
    var troca = 
    {
        sen: "Math.sin",
        cos: "Math.cos",
        e: "Math.E",
        ln: "Math.log",  
    }

    poli = poli.replace(/sen|cos|e|ln/gi, function(matched){
      return troca[matched];
    });

    function fdex(x)
    {
        return eval(poli);
    }
```

Comment: É uma boa iniciativa perguntar em como evitar um eval, mas o essencial já foi dito nos comentários da sua pergunta anterior. A resposta dada aqui é um excelente ponto de partida para implementar o parser sugerido. Segue pesquisa que pode servir de partida: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+polynomial+parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi seroa mais ou menos isso:

```js
var funcoes = {
    sen: Math.sin,
    cos: Math.cos,
    e: Math.E,
    ln: Math.log,  
}
var funcao = "sen";
console.log(funcoes[funcao](30));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ExecutionFromArray.js).

Em vez de usar textos eu peguei as funções mesmo e só as chamei sem precisar do `eval()`. Um resumo grosseiro do `eval()` é tirar as aspas de um texto e executar o que estava ali dentro, então por que não tirar as aspas no seu código mesmo?

Acho que responde o resto do questionamento: [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101).

Note que para pegar expressões gerais terá que fazer um *parser* do mesmo jeito, e aí dá para usar uma forma um pouco diferente disso, a resposta foi em cima do código apresentado e não do contexto todo que depois eu vi que já existia em outra pergunta do AP.

Comment: Então. Essa variável "troca" serve apenas para o usuário não precisar digitar Math.sin() quando for fazer a operação. Tornando mais amigável para quem não conhece JS e a biblioteca Math.

Comment: Sm, isso está na pergunta. Tem alguma parte que não entendeu da resposta, ou que ache que precise ser melhor explicada?

Comment: O eval está sendo utilizado para receber a função como um todo nessa parte em específico:

function inserirLinhaTabela() 
{

    //Cálculo numérico: 

    var poli = document.getElementById("fx").value;

function fdex(x)
    {
        return eval(poli);
    }