# Como converter e executar uma fórmula em PHP?

Tags: php

Olá, preciso executar uma fórmula que está em string.
Essa fórmula vem de um atributo da tabela do BD.
Exemplo:
formula = "{{c1}} - {{c2}}"

Obtenho  a string vinda do banco no formato acima.
Faço a substituição dos valores c1 e c2 por números desta forma:

```
$a1 = 2;
$a2 = 1;
$formula = "{{c1}} - {{c2}}";
$f = str_replace("{{c1}}",$a1,$formula);
$f = str_replace("{{c2}}", $a2, $f);

print($f); // resultado = "2 - 1"
```

Preciso executar este cálculo.
Resultado esperado na execução: 1.
Como fazer?

Comment: Isso me lembra [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128845)

Comment: Se não for com `eval`, você provavelmente terá que criar seu próprio "compilador de fórmulas" , com regex. Não é muito recomendado usar `eval` se não souber o que tá fazendo.

Comment: A fórmula sempre vem com o mesmo sinal?

Comment: A fórmula pode conter as 4 operações de uma vez. Pode ter fórmulas complexas.

Comment: Já tentou usar uma lib que tenha isso? [Exemplo](https://github.com/denissimon/formula-parser/blob/master/FormulaParser.php)

Comment: Vou implementar a lib sugerida e retorno se tiver sucesso. obrigado por enquando.

Comment: Tem [essa](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) também, só tem que ver se não é a bazuka para matar formiga

Comment: Wallace Maxies, a FormulaParser funcionou muito bem. Fiz alguns testes e está ok. Poderia adicionar como resposta para outros colegas?

Comment: Olha essa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880821/6754506):

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118994/discussion-on-question-by-marcelo-gomes-como-converter-e-executar-uma-formula-em)

Answer (score 2):

Para processar uma string em PHP e transformá-la em um resultado "real", você talvez precise percorrer um caminho, digamos, complicado...

### Eval, uma possibilidade, mas eu descartaria...

Primeiramente, é provável que a forma mais fácil [em termos de "tamanho de código"] de executar esse código seria usando o infame `eval`.

Exemplo:

```php
$a1 = 2;
$a2 = 1;
$formula = "{{c1}} - {{c2}}";

$codigo = strtr($formula, [
   '{{c1}}' => $a1,
   '{{c2}}' => $a2,
]);

$resultado = eval(sprintf('return %s;', $codigo));
```

Uma observação importante que precisa ser feita (e vou colocar em negrito inclusive), é que **Você deve evitar usar `eval` o máximo possível, a menos que você saiba bem o que está fazendo**.

[Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128851/4995) do Maniero aqui no site mostra bem os cuidados que devem ser tomados.

### Escrever um parser

Outra forma é você escrever uma função que vai analisar a sua string para interpretar sua fórmula e retornar um resultado. É uma tarefa não muito fácil, porque você vai ter que escrever uma função/classe que interprete sua string e efetue operações complexas.

No meu caso, fiz uma de exemplo, mas está bem simples:

```php
function formula_parser($formula)
{
    $parts = array_map('trim', preg_split('/(\d+)/', $formula, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

    $total = 0;
    $operator = '+';

    foreach ($parts as $key => $part) {
        
        if (! is_numeric($part)) {
            $operator = $part;
            continue;
        }

        switch ($operator) {
            case '+':
                $total += $part;
                break;
            case '-':
                $total -= $part;
                break;
            case '*':
                $total *= $part;
                break;
            case '/':
                $total /= $part;
                break;
        }
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Resultados:

```
$formulas = [
    '1 + 3 + 4',
    '3 - 5 + 4',
    '3 * 5 * 10',
    '10 * 10 / 5'
];

foreach ($formulas as $formula) {
    var_dump(formula_parser($formula));
}

// int(8)
// int(2)
// int(150)
// int(20)
```

**É óbvio que a função acima é apenas uma pequena demonstração**, mas note a quantidade de coisas que precisaram ser feitas para fazer operações matemáticas simples (essa função de exemplo nem suporta float, inclusive).

### Usar biliotecas

Talvez seja a opção mais viável. Existem algumas bibliotecas que possuem parser escritos para facilitar sua vida.

Lembro-me da [Symfony Language Expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) e a [Formular Parser](https://github.com/denissimon/formula-parser).

Se observar o código-fonte de alguma delas, vai observar que escrever um "parser de fórmula" não é uma coisa tão simples, mas talvez uma dessas dicas possam ajudar.