# Qual expressão regular utilizar para realizar a substituição de símbolos em uma string?

Tags: javascript, string, regex, replace

Tenho uma string, tal como `"1x2,4÷4"` e quero substituir o `x` por `*`; a `,` por `.` e o `÷` por `/` usando o `replace` do JavaScript.

Qual expressão regular eu precisaria utilizar para fazer essa substituição?

Por exemplo:

```
let expression = "5,5x8÷7";

expression = expression.replace('???', '???');
// Deveria estar assim "5.5*8/7"

resolveExpression(expression);

function resolveExpression(exp) {
  // Resolve a expressão
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Não precisa de regex**, e mesmo que precisasse ainda sim você teria que usar um loop, como for ou while para resolver outras coisas.

Criar um simples objeto para mapear o que deseja substituir e usar [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) com string já resolve:

```js
let expression = "5,5x8÷7";
const expressoes = { ',': '.', 'x': '*', '÷': '/' };

for (const [exp, value] of Object.entries(expressoes)) {
  expression = expression.replaceAll(exp, value);
}

console.log(expression);
```

Claro que se o objetivo é usar isso com `eval()`, provavelmente será algo "atrapalhado", apesar de funcionar existem diversos problemas que podem ocorrer devido a entrada de dados que não dá para controlar totalmente, o melhor seria criar algo próprio ou usar um biblioteca existente que já o faça, como https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs (deve ter libs menores que fazem só a parte que deseja, essa faz muito mais, depois edito se encontrar alguma que realmente seja simples e eficiente).

---

Versão ES5:

Como `const [...]` e `replaceAll` são mais modernos, se desejar algo para navegadores antigos irá necessitar de regex ainda (daria pra fazer com `String.prototype.split()` também):

```js
var expression = "5,5x8÷7";
var expressoes = { ',': '.', 'x': '*', '÷': '/' };

for (var exp in expressoes) {
  expression = expression.replace(new RegExp(exp, 'g'), expressoes[exp]);
}

console.log(expression);
```

Com `split` pode até dar certo e aparentar se mais rápido, mas vai depender um pouco do tamanho do valor de entrada, no geral ainda sim foi 3% mais rápido, o que é algo ínfimo:

```js
var expression = "5,5x8÷7";
var expressoes = { ',': '.', 'x': '*', '÷': '/' };

for (var exp in expressoes) {
  expression = expression.split(exp).join(expressoes[exp]);
}

console.log(expression);
```

No entanto o mais rápido foi a sugestão da outra resposta, trabalhando `char` a `char` como pode ver no benchmark: https://jsbench.me/usko4noh4h/5, sendo em média 55% mais rápido que os demais, o que para tratar diversas expressões será bastante vantajoso em questão de tempo:

```
let output = '';

for (const char of expression) {
  output += char in expressoes ? expressoes[char] : char;
}
```

Um equivalente para ES5 seria (usando `for` "normal"):

```js
var expression = "5,5x8÷7";
var expressoes = { ',': '.', 'x': '*', '÷': '/' };

var output = '';

for (var i = 0, j = expression.length; i < j; i++) {
  var char = expression[i];

  output += char in expressoes ? expressoes[char] : char;
}

console.log(output);
```

O mais rápido foi com for "normal":

[image: for increment apresentou o resultado mais rápido]

Comment: Vale lembrar que o `String.prototype.replace`, quando utilizado com string no primeiro argumento, não faz o _replace_ de _todas_ as ocorrências; somente da primeira. Nesse tipo de situação, eu acharia preferível utilizar o `String.prototype.replaceAll`.

Comment: @LuizFelipe sim, falha minha, faltou o "global", ajustado.

Comment: Depois se quiser fazer o _benchmark_ com a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/507329/69296), ficarei feliz em saber.

Comment: @LuizFelipe muito provavelmente usar char vai ser muito mais eficiente que qualquer coisa, já que opera dentro do proprio valor, em qualquer motor, mas já adiciono.

Comment: Também coloquei uma resposta - só pra servir de exemplo do que não fazer :-) - mas acho que nem precisa colocar no benchmark, é quase certeza que será mais lenta... cc @LuizFelipe

Comment: @hkotsubo e luiz, coloquei a "versão ES5" do código (usando for "normal") e ela foi a mais rápida, sendo pelo menos 50% mais eficiente que as demais.

Answer (score 7):

Apenas como alternativa à [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/507313/69296), pode-se resolver esse problema com apenas uma varredura da string ao invés de uma varredura para cada *token* mapeado em decorrência do uso de `String.prototype.replaceAll`.

Como cada *token* possui um único caractere, essa tarefa torna-se trivial:

```js
const input = '5,5x8÷7';

const tokenMap = {
  ',': '.',
  'x': '*',
  '÷': '/'
};

let output = '';
for (const char of input) {
  output += char in tokenMap ? tokenMap[char] : char;
}

console.log(output);
```

E para a posterior análise desse tipo de expressão, mantenho a observação do colega alertando para o uso indevido de `eval` ([saiba mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/69296)). Talvez seja o caso de construir um pequeno *parser* para criar uma árvore sintática a partir da string. A partir da árvore, pode-se avaliá-la seguindo a ordem de precedência dos operadores.

Existe uma série de artigos sobre isso na internet. Não entrarei em muitos detalhes, mas é um bom exercício.

Answer (score 5):

Complementando as outras respostas - e reforçando para **não** usar regex, já que as soluções propostas pelos demais são mais adequadas do que expressões regulares - veja como ficaria desnecessariamente mais complicado com regex:

```js
const input = '5,5x8÷7';
const tokenMap = {
  ',': '.',
  'x': '*',
  '÷': '/'
};

const operadores = Object.keys(tokenMap).map(s => "\\" + s);
const r = RegExp(`[${operadores.join('')}]`, 'g');

let output = input.replace(r, function(m) { return tokenMap[m] });
console.log(output);
```

Ou seja, eu construo uma regex com os operadores que quero substituir. Como cada operador tem apenas um caractere, eu posso usar uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), delimitada por colchetes.

No caso acima, a regex ficaria `[\,\x\÷]`, ou seja, é uma expressão que pega qualquer um desses caracteres. Eu adicionei a `\` por precaução, para o caso de ter algum caractere que precise de escape (nenhum desses precisa, mas se tiver algum que precise, estará devidamente escapado).

E no `replace` eu pego o operador que foi encontrado e troco pelo respectivo caractere do `tokenMap`. Ou seja, além de usar uma regex - que já tem um certo custo, provavelmente maior que as soluções das outras respostas - ainda tem as chamadas do *callback* sendo feitas para cada operador encontrado.

Além de desnecessariamente mais complicado, provavelmente ainda será mais lenta. Mas fica aqui como registro do que não fazer...

Answer (score 4):

Ainda complementando as outras respostas é também possível obter a saída desejada usando princípios de [programação funcional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_funcional).

```js
const input = '5,5x8÷7';
const tokenMap = {
  ',': '.',
  'x': '*',
  '÷': '/'
};
output = [...input].map((c) => (c in tokenMap) ? tokenMap[c] : c).join("");
console.log(output);
```

A expressão `[...input].map((c) => (c in tokenMap) ? tokenMap[c] : c).join("")` pode ser interpretada da seguinte forma:

- `[...input]`: quebra a entrada em um array de caracteres.
- `map((c) => (c in tokenMap) ? tokenMap[c] : c)`: para cada caractere `c` é aplicada uma função anônima que verifica se este caractere é uma chave em `tokenMap`:

  - Se sim, faz o mapeamento e o retorna.
  - Se não, apenas retorna o caractere.
- `.join("")`: junta o resultado numa string.

Referências:

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Sintaxe de Espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)