# Como criar um avaliador de expressões?

Tags: c#

Estou criando um programa que permitirá ao usuário criar e executar suas próprias expressões.
Pesquisando a respeito, encontrei o [`Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) do `DataTable`.
Ex:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var exp = dt.Compute("10 * (12+4) / 3", "");
```

Com esse comando o usuário poderá digitar apenas fórmulas matemáticas, mas, não por exemplo um código para ele (usuário) criar uma caixa de texto em tempo de execução.
Ex:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var exp = dt.Compute(@"MessageBox.Show(""Teste de messagebox"", ""Título"");", "");
```

Como posso fazer isso?
*Se possível, sem qualquer livraria externa.*

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101

Comment: A ideia é só um avaliador matemático? Ou você quer mais alguma coisa? Quais os operadores que gostaria de implementar?

Comment: Que pudesse digitar qualquer coisa, como até classes.

Comment: Ah, então já está respondido.