# Como inserir as referências para utilizar a classe ScriptEngine?

Tags: c#, nuget

Com base na pergunta [Compilar string como código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15428/compilar-string-como-c%C3%B3digo) inclui em meu projeto a classe `ScriptEngine`, no entanto, ela não está sendo encontrada nas referencias:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp; //Nesta
```

Fazendo a instalação através do **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution** busquei por `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting` e o instalei, mas, não deixou instalar o próximo (`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp`) por incompatibilidade.
[image: Incompatibilidade]

Eu consigo instalar a referência `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp` pelo console com os comandos (em ordem no console):

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native
>   PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp -Pre

**Mas desta forma, o `ScriptEngine` não está sendo encontrado.**

O que devo fazer para utilizar o `ScriptEngine`?