# Como compilar código C# em tempo de execução em um projeto ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Tentei utilizar o `CodeDom`, mas ao tentar buscar uma `DLL` específica para executar meu código o comando `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` sempre me retorna `null`.

Ao que parece, os projetos `ASP.NET` são executados e gerenciados pelo `IIS` (**obviamente**) e utilizam um diretório temporário.

Gostaria de uma solução para que, na minha aplicação web, o usuário digitasse o código `C#` e então esse código fosse enviado ao servidor, compilado e executado para devolver uma resposta ao usuário.

Em projetos `Windows` ou `Console`, tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas em uma solução `DDD` com o `Start Up Project` como uma aplicação `ASP.NET MVC5` isso não funciona.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101

Comment: @Maniero obrigado pela resposta, mas não é bem isso que resolverá meu problema. Eu já tentei fazer dessa maneira e funciona para projetos windows mas não para projetos ASP.NET, o real motivo eu não tenho certeza, mas tem a ver com o fato de projetos ASP.NET serem executados pelo IIS e o mesmo gerar execução com arquivos TEMP.