# Como criar variáveis variáveis em C# da mesma forma que se faz em PHP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variáveis, dinâmico

É possível utilizar variáveis variáveis ou algo semelhante em C# como no PHP por exemplo?

```
$example = "etc..";
$var = "example";

// variáveis variáveis
echo $$var; // etc...
echo ${$var}; // etc...
```

Caso não seja possível, porque? A tipagem, estrutura, etc...não permite ou simplesmente porque não tem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso já é uma enorme gambiarra em PHP. Em C# é pior ainda por ser uma linguagem que incentiva resolver tudo em tempo de compilação.

Quase sempre (uns 99+%) que alguém faz isso na verdade está querendo usar um [*array*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou uma [tabela *hash*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (mapa, dicionário, *array* associativo).

Quando não é uma destas coisas a pessoa está querendo fazer algo errado e não tem noção disso ou tem algum outro mecanismo que atende melhor.

Um desses mecanismos seria a [compilação em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101), que raramente é necessária, e se for, poucas pessoas conseguem fazer com segurança.

Não tem um mecanismo específico porque não precisa e porque ele não deveria existir em nenhuma linguagem. Então dá para obter o resultado esperado, mas não com esse mecanismo.