# Qual é a diferença entre as extensões KTS e KT?

Tags: kotlin, extensão

Estou estudando Kotlin e abri um projeto Spring Boot por curiosidade. Me deparei com dois arquivos de extensões diferentes, contento código Kotlin: `.kts` e `.kt`.

Qual é a diferença entre essas duas extensões?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin suporta a execução em modo *script* de forma mais ou menos interpretada, então é possível executar algo através de um texto, mais ou menos como é possível em linguagens [como C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101) através do [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101). Como estes códigos costumam ter uma semântica ligeiramente diferente de um código para rodar compilado mesmo diretamente no executável, é melhor ter uma separação. Então o `.kts` costuma ser usado para indicar que o código ali deve ser executado pelo [**mecanismo de *script***](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support), e o `.kt` é o **fonte de que deverá ser compilado** e gerado um código que será executado pela JVM ou outra VM compatível.

Por isso que eu falo que essas tecnologias estão mais preparadas para atender todos cenários.

Note que este mecanismo de *script* deve rodar dentro de Kotlin, ele não é um *shell*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

**KT** é um arquivo de origem do Kotlin, ou seja, um arquivo com o código fonte da aplicação. Um arquivo normal com o código fonte.

**KTS** é um arquivo de Script Shell do Kotlin. Um arquivo de Script.

Você pode encontrar mais informações aqui:

- [What’s the deference between .kt and .kts files](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/whats-the-deference-between-kt-and-kts-files-jet-and-jetl-files/1058/5)
- [File extensions, .kt, .kts?](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/file-extensions-kt-kts/1238)
- [What is the different between Kotlin File/Class and Kotlin Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083639/what-is-the-different-between-kotlin-file-class-and-kotlin-script)