# Exeção System.PlatformNotSupportedException ao tentar compilar codigo com o CodeDOM

Tags: c#, .net, string, compilação, scripting

Eu estou usando um código, que eu vi em uma resposta [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15428/compilar-string-como-c%C3%B3digo) pagina:

```
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(
                    new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "teste.exe", true)
        {
            GenerateExecutable = true
        };
       CompilerResults compiledAssembly = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"
    using System;
    class Program {
      public static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello world."");
      }
    }");

        var errors = compiledAssembly.Errors
                                     .Cast<CompilerError>()
                                     .ToList();

        if (errors.Any())
        {
            errors.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            return;
        }

        Module module = compiledAssembly.CompiledAssembly.GetModules()[0];

        Type mt = null;
        if (module != null)
            mt = module.GetType("Program");

        MethodInfo methInfo = null;
        if (mt != null)
            methInfo = mt.GetMethod("Main");

        if (methInfo != null)
            Console.WriteLine(methInfo.Invoke(null, null));
```

Porem quando tento compilar recebo o seguinte error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131539
  Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.
  Source=System.CodeDom
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at ConsoleApp7.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\THIAGO\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7\Program.cs:line 18
```

Estou usando essas referencias:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: Algumas das classes desse namespace são incompletas, algumas são só exemplos. É um projeto .Net Core ou Framework?

Comment: Acho que .Net Core.

Comment: é um aplicativo console com o primeiro código no main, e as referencias listadas acima.

Comment: Algumas coisas são diferentes para .Net Core e .Net Framework pois o Core é desenvolvido para ser multiplataforma. Dê uma olhada nesse código: https://laurentkempe.com/2019/02/18/dynamically-compile-and-run-code-using-dotNET-Core-3.0/